# Jpa Respository and its tests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

This is more of a question regarding concept rather than an error I am facing.
So here I have two JPA respositories refereing to two tables in database
Teacher - has foreign key reference to departmentid
Depeartment - contains depeartment infos

Now to test the DepartmentRepositoryIntegrationTest I have to delete all the entries of teachers and then the depeartments. I understand I have a foreign key reference to departments so I cant delete any entry inside the department which is being consumed by the Teacher table. But When I was running this test there was nothing saved or inserted in the teachers table still I was getting `DataIntergityViolationException`. Why was there such enforcement to delete teachers table entries even though it was empty manually???
Couldnt find anything relevant to my doubt.
I am running the tests against the inmemory database like H2.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
  "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;loginTimeout=30;",
  "spring.datasource.username="random",
  "spring.datasource.password="random"
})
public class DepartmentRepositoryIntegrationTest {

  @Autowired
  private DepartmentRepository departmentRepository;

  @Autowired
  private FacultyRepository facultyRepository;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    departmentRepository.deleteAll();
    facultyRepository.deleteAll();
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting the teachers first and move forward?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong ordering actually so I had faculty deleted before the department .. but my question is more of related to this thing that why I have to go down this road ... Of deleting faculty ..why can't I just delete the department as I don't have anything inside faculty.

Comment: Sometimes there could be early tests data(when executing one after the other) in H2 db when you run these tests. There is a way of reading through H2 db to see if there are.